# Java Streams API: Apply a filter to a field of the objects to be filtered

Tags: java, collections

Inspired by the Stream API's way of composing small functions, and by `Comparator.comparing` which allows me to create comparators that compare certain fields, I'm looking for a similar style to create predicates that test certain fields.

Given this `record Foo(String id, String name) { }` and given a collection `x` of `Foo`, I want to compute a smaller collection `y` of `Foo` where the name matches a certain regular expression.  It is very convenient to convert a regular expression into a predicate, let's say `m = Pattern.compile(...).asMatchPredicate()`.

Now, of course `y = x.stream().filter(f -> m.test(x.name())).toList()` will do the trick.  But I'm looking for convenience methods in a style similar to `Comparator.comparing`...

`y = x.stream().filter(Predicates.testField(Foo::name, m)).toList()` -- something like this, perhaps?

Is this in the JDK?  Is this worth having, do you think?  Does a library exist that does this?

(Of course, I can't do `x.stream().map(Foo::name).filter(m).toList()` because that gives me a list of names, not a list of `Foo`.)

Comment: `f -> m.test(x.name())` f.name, right?

Comment: There is no such method, but you could write your own in ~3 lines. I fail to see how the `Predicates.testField` version is better, though. It's both longer and adds unnecessary indirection.

Comment: The reason Comparable.comparing is good, and your suggestion is (IMO) not, is because the former forces the supplied type to be an implementer of Comparable. That type narrowing is where the value comes from. It's converting a `Supplier<Comparable>` to a `Comparator`. Your version is just calling `test` indirectly rather than directly, so isn't generating any value.